# Available build tasks in TFS 2017

Tags: team-foundation-server

In contrast to the available build tasks in my personal VSTS instance:

[image: VSTS]

I have another (seems like older) set of tasks available on a my client's TFS instance (e.g. a ".Net Core (Preview)" task):

[image: TFS]

What does the TFS admin have to do in order to update these? Where should I point him to in order to get to know why the set of available build tasks is different?

Answer (score 0):

If the TFS server is internet connected, a number of tasks can update directly from the Visual Studio Marketplace. Other tasks will only be updated with the server Update packs (e.g. TFS 2017 update 3) or with Major version (TFS 2018).

Depending on whether the tasks are available from an open source repository, you may be able to use `tfx` to push the tasks directly to the TFS server's local marketplace.

Preview tasks generally don't ship with TFS server updates though, since they're updated more often and may require to be pushed to the server at a higher frequency.